# Iterate over equal_range result set

Tags: c++, multimap, unordered-map

I have the following unordered multimap:

```
std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int > duplicates;
```

And I try to get the values of a key using

```
std::pair<std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int>,std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int> > range = duplicates.equal_range(id);
```

And then using a for loop to get the multiple results:

```
for (std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int>::iterator it=range.first; it!=range.second; ++it)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ref_impl/core.cpp:306:84: error: conversion from 'std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int>' to non-scalar type 'std::tr1::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<const unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, unsigned int> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const unsigned int, unsigned int> >, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::tr1::hash<unsigned int>, std::tr1::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::tr1::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::tr1::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, false>::iterator {aka std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, unsigned int>, false, false>}' requested
ref_impl/core.cpp:306:101: error: no match for 'operator!=' in 'it != range.std::pair<std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::second'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unordered_multimap::equal_range` returns a pair of iterators, not a pair of `unordered_multimap`s. Change the second line to the following, and everything should work:

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int>::iterator iterator;
std::pair<iterator, iterator> range = duplicates.equal_range(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `range` as a pair of unordered maps, rather than unordered map iterators.  Thank god for auto.  Are you sure you can't use it?  It would make your life so much easier:

```
auto range = duplicates.equal_range(id);
```

Otherwise, you should make liberal use of `typedef`.

Comment: I get the following when I use auto: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]

Comment: @salamis: What compiler are you using?  Try adding `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` to the command line when you compile.

Comment: I am using 4.7.2 on Mac OS

Comment: I assume that's GCC?  Then the command line option I specified should work.